# How can I find Nikon D600 + Nikkor AF 80-200 f2.8 D photo samples?

Tags: nikon, picture-samples, nikon-d600

Is there any way we could see some photos from the new **Nikon D600 and 80-200 f2.8 D ED** combo? Over at Flickr, or someplace else—maybe?

I could scarcely find "tags" with 80-200 f2.8D and Nikon D600 together
nor any compelling discussion at Flickr.

All I've seen is here: http://www.facebook.com/fotografkristianohlsson, which has just two or three nice samples.

Comment: http://www.flickriver.com/ has a lens explorer, you could try that.

Comment: Google, Bing images search engines can help you. Or you can une 500Px

Comment: I have one, and there are a few models of that lens, which one, the one-touch, or 2-touch version for example?  What is it you're hoping to see in those images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your search string is rather specific. Try removing some of the attributes to find a broader range of photos.

Here's a search on flickr for "[D600 80-200 f2.8](http://www.flickr.com/search/?ss=2&w=all&q=D600%2080-200%20f2.8&m=text)".

One for "[D600 80-200](http://www.flickr.com/search/?ss=2&w=all&q=D600%2080-200&m=text)".

These might not be exact results as there are a few different generations of the 80-200mm, but should provide a close approximation.

Pixel Peeper also has a search similar to flick river. Might try there as well. Here's a search for the [80-200 f/2.8](http://www.pixel-peeper.com/adv/?lens=222&camera=none&perpage=12&focal_min=none&focal_max=none&aperture_min=none&aperture_max=none&iso_min=none&iso_max=none&exp_min=none&exp_max=none&res=3).